# Type hints for MetPy quantities

Tags: type-hinting, metpy

I am trying to use type hints throughout my code. For metpy quantities, I find this to be quite hard as they inherit from pint.

If I check the type of the quantities I am using I find out that they are
pint.quantity.build_quantity_class..Quantity
But I don't want to have this type written in a type hint.

Is there a shorter/clearer way and best practice for type hints of metpy quantities (and other similar complex objects)?

Answer (score 0):

The MetPy project itself has not done much with type hints, but you might want to take a look at the [Pull Request](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/pull/1259) that added some typing information to Pint itself.